# How to display image here

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

**Hi there, how can i display image here**(its example place on the photo but it will be nice if i can put image here) **from field `Image` but not after saving but live**(when i paste url then display preview). **I dont have any idea how to do that so the last thing is to write a question here.**

[image: Example place where i want to display my image.]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use custom admin templates, then use JavaScript

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).